# Find the density of Z = min (X,Y)

Tags: probability

Let X= Geometric $(p_1=\dfrac{1}{3})$, Y=Geometric $(p_1=\dfrac{2}{5})$ be independent.

a) Find the density of $Z$= min ($X,Y$).

b) Find P($Z=2$) as a numerical fraction.

(Hint: Look at P ($Z \geq z$). )

My attempt:

$\textbf{a) Find the density of $Z$= min ($X,Y$).}$

First, we find the density of $Z= min (X,Y)$ by using the fact that $P ($S$ \geq s) = t^s$ when S = Geometric ($p$) and $t=1-p$, with $0 < p < 1$.

\begin{align*} 
P (Z \geq z) &= P (X \geq z, Y \geq z) \\
&=P (X \geq z)  P(Y \geq z) \\
&= (q_1)^z \cdot (q_2)^z \\
&= (q_1q_2)^z
\end{align*}
Since $p_1= \dfrac{1}{3}$, we have $q_1 = \dfrac{2}{3}$. And since $p_2 = \dfrac{2}{5}$, we have   $q_2= \dfrac{3}{5}$. Thus, 
\begin{align}
P (Z \geq z) = (q_1q_2)^z = \left(\dfrac{2}{3} \cdot \dfrac{3}{5} \right)^z = \left (\dfrac{2}{5} \right)^z.
\end{align} 
Since $q= \dfrac{2}{5}$, it follows that $Z=$Geometric $\left(p = \dfrac{3}{5} \right)$.

$\textbf{b) Find P($Z=2$) as a numerical fraction. }$

By part a, since $Z=$Geometric $\left(p = \dfrac{3}{5} \right)$, we have 
\begin{align} 
P(Z = z) = \dfrac{3}{5} \left(\dfrac{2}{5}\right)^z.
\end{align}
Thus, 
\begin{align} 
P(Z = 2) &= \dfrac{3}{5} \left(\dfrac{2}{5}\right)^2 \\
&= \dfrac{12}{125}.
\end{align}

Is my work correct? Thank you in advance!

Edit: To put this question into perspective, here is a snippet from the book I am learning Probability from (by Hoel). See part (a).:

[image]

Comment: $Z$ is a discrete random variable, so it doesn't have a density.  I think you mean "probability mass function".

Comment: This problem is from class and I've typed it as written by my professor. This problem is from a chapter on Discrete Random Variables and their discrete density functions. In particular, $P(Z=z)$ is a density function  of Z = min(X,Y), where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.  Does it change things if we say "Find the distribution of min (X,Y)?"

Comment: Personally, I find the terminology "discrete density function" rather barbaric: "probability mass function" is more standard.  OK, it's a density (in the measure-theoretic sense) with respect to counting measure.  But if you just say "the density" without qualifying it somehow, people are going to think you mean density with respect to Lebesgue measure (as you get with continuous random variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way of seeing this.  A geometric random variable with parameter $p$ can be realized as the number of failures before the first success in a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p$.  If $S_n$ is a sequence of Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p_1$ and $T_n$ a sequence of trials with probability of success $p_2$, all independent, and $X$ and $Y$ are the numbers of failures before the first success in $S_n$ and $T_n$ respectively, then $\min(X,Y)$ is the number of failures before the first success in $S_n$ or $T_n$.
Since the probability of success in $S_n$ or $T_n$ is $1 - (1-p_1)(1-p_2) = p_1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2$, $\min(X,Y)$ is geometric with parameter $p_1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2$.

Comment: This is not the method I learned in class, but thank you for this perspective! It is another way of seeing the problem. I substituted in values for $p_1$ and $p_2$ and we indeed obtain the same min ($X,Y$) with geometric $p = \dfrac{3}{5}$. Thank you!